# Export file over written

Tags: c#, excel, windowsformshost

I am currently using `Microsoft.Office.Core;` and `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` to export my data from windows form to excel.

When I export my file it always gets overwritten.

Does anyone know of a way to solve it?

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file d:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
```

Comment: I cancelled your last edit and rolled back to the previous version. Your edit changed the whole question and therefore invalidated the existing answer. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could first check if the file name you want already exists and attach a DateTime at its end if so. Also a '@' before a path gives you opportunity to type your path just like in the explorer (without double '\'):

```
string MyExportFile = "csharp-Excel";
string FullPath = @"d:\";

if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(FullPath, MyExportFile)))
{
     MyExportFile += DateTime.Now + ".xls";
     FullPath += MyExportFile;
}

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(FullPath, 
    Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
    misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
    misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

  xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
  xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work it does not let me specify where do i want to save my file to